# Using CSS or Javascript, how do I fix orphan text in Chinese characters on a responsive web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have a site that is localised in Chinese .
On some paragraphs (p tag) I have an orphaned character which my client is complaining about.

e.g

> 此处显示新此处显示新此处显示新此处显示新此处显示新此处显示
>
> 处

Since there are no spaces between characters, I can't just put a  or line-break between the last two words. 
The text is dynamic and CMS driven, so I can't explicitly insert anything in the text. 
The web page is responsive, the width of this paragraph changes depending on the screen width

Any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Comment: What is the desired behavior? By the way, please proof-read your post.

Comment: Obviously I don't want orphaned text.

Comment: You say that you can't explicitly insert anything in the text. Are you also unable to run JS to modify the text?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to somehow process the text, then arrange to put the last two or three characters in a `nowrap` span:

```
<div >此处显示新此处显示新此处显示处显<span style="white-space: nowrap; ">示处</span></div>
```

If you are not able to modify the text in this way, then I would say you are out of luck. There is no CSS property to handle this type of widow-prevention. However, there may be alternative solutions involving zero-width spaces, `<wbr>` elements, and/or the `word-break` property which could be worth looking into.